# Using Select statement twice for same column of table for MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm supposed to write a query for a database that is a little tricky for me.
It has an EMPLOYEE table that has these attributes(columns): Emp_Id,Name,Age, Dept_ID, Salary

It also has a DEPARTMENT table that has these attributes(columns): Dep_Id, Dep_Name, Location, Mgr_Id.

I am being asked to list the Employees Names, their Locations and their Manager's Name.
The Manager is(of course) an employee Meaning I'm goign to have to select from Name twice. So how can I make a query where I can display both the Name of both the Employee and the manager. I can do one or the other but I have no clue how to do both in the same query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `Mgr_Id` has a foreign key relation with `Emp_id` in the EMPLOYEE table, you can do the following:

```
SELECT
e.Name as EmployeeName,
d.Location AS EmployeeLocation,
de.Name AS ManagerName
FROM EMPLOYEE AS e
LEFT OUTER JOIN DEPARTMENT AS d
ON d.Dep_Id = e.Dept_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN EMPLOYEE AS de
ON de.Mrg_Id = e.Emp_Id
```

The key point to take away is the use of `AS` to use table aliases so you can reference a table more than once, for different records. Technically, the `AS` itself is optional, but I left it in for clarity.